# PSOD vmwar eSXi 6.7 U1

Tags: vmware-esxi

I have a ESX 6.7 U1 installed on my HP Proliant DL 380 G9 with a configuration of 2 CPUs Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2630L v3 @ 1.80GHz (32 cores) with 32 GB Ram.

Recently the server has crashed many times, showing the Purple Screen of Death. Once this happens all of the virtual machines on the server stops and crashes until I restart this server.

How can I fix PSOD problem?

[image: screenshot of error]

Comment: At first glance it looks like an issue with your memory, have you got any more you can swap out to see if that helps? Any errors in the iLO faults page?